# How can I make my page scrollable horizontally on xs screen sizes?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a minimum width for the entire page so that it overflows on screen sizes smaller than this minimum width but the content is currently taking the width of the screen.

In other words: I was expecting this implementation to make the page scrollable horizontally on screen sizes smaller than 350px width.

```
body {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  min-width: 350px;
}

@media (min-width: 350px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
```

However, when I lower the screen size the page keeps shrinking beyond 350px.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body {
 overflow-x: auto;
 min-width: 350px;
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
 body {
   overflow-x: scroll;
 }
}
```

Comment: Got the same behavior :( But thanks anyway